# Why do I need valid HTML-files as fragment container when running sonarqube?

Tags: java, html, sonarqube, thymeleaf

In our java project we are using spring+thymeleaf for generating/templating the gui. Sonarqube analysis our quality and and stumbels upon some html-files we use only for storing fragments in -> use as fragment container.
All fragments are lying in a folder, which is seprated to the folder for the page-templates.

Is there a possibility to avoid those errors?

- "title" should be present in all pages
- Favicons should be used in all pages

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [exclusions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) to either ignore these files altogether, or to ignore issues from those specific rules on that set of files.

Comment: Due to complex project/company responsibilities we can only change the properties-files. in this we can not specify "ignores" on file/rule basis. Is there another way?